# Are "populist" and "policy" synonymous?

Tags: meaning

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

The opposition parties on Sunday demanded that the Bhartiya Janta Party led state government should refrain from making populist or policy decisions.

Populist means related to populism. 
Is it anyhow synonymous with policy?

Comment: no this looks like bad english to me, can you include the dictionary definitions of the 2 words, see if you can find an overlap

Comment: No. Note that the article in question puts *populist* in quotes and cites a Opposition leader as decrying the government's tendency to make "populist" statements instead of addressing problems.

Comment: The sentence further down makes more sense "he hoped the government will not make any “populist announcement” unlike those made in the Budget presented by Union finance minister Piyush Goyal, or take any policy decision."

Comment: @StoneyB- so you are implying that the sentence is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In the context of the sentence, "or" is used to offset two separate things [populist {decisions} or policy {decisions}, and the opposition party wants the Bhartiya Janta Party led state government to refrain doing either.

As WendyG states, examine these two words in the dictionary.

Populist can be a noun or adjective.  In this case, it's an adjective modifying "decisions."  Def: [adj] relating to or characteristic of a political approach that strives to appeal to ordinary people who feel that their concerns are disregarded by established elite groups: [www.dict.com]

Policy is a noun with two definitions. 1 of 2: a definite course or method of action selected from among alternatives and in light of given conditions to guide and determine present and future decisions   - best fit. [www.merriam-webster.com]

So, basically inside the government, the ruling party is presently the elected party, and is empowered to create laws or policy. Policy on how the State government will function [Policy]

Outside government policy, and dealing directly with the general public, the ruling party appealing to the general public and answering their concerns makes them more popular among the people [Populist]

Maybe at the time of this article in "The Hindu," India's election took place and another party was voted in office.  It's a cry for the outgoing party to simply refrain doing either until the other elected party takes over.

Nice post. Cheers!